# time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby on Rails, and I installed all the necessary applications and updates for gems. I already exhausted/researched most of all possible answer for this error and tried all of it, but still am having no luck.

```
/Users/u=Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': cannot load such file -- false (LoadError)
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
   from /Users/Username/Downloads/job4quote/config/application.rb:7:in `'
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in '
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
   from /Users/Username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `'
   from script/rails:6:in `require'
   from script/rails:6:in `'
```

Is there a way to access these .rb files to make necessary changes?

As shown here -> [warning: circular argument reference](https://github.com/tmm1/rails/commit/8fd52705eda6a2cd7e9a8a5bc723fa094e359eb7)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be caused by the higher version of ruby (In my case rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.2) and using an older version of rails. One solution in which worked for me was to use ruby 2.0 and to update my gem file (RVM Capistrano).

`gem 'rvm-capistrano',  require: false`

run the bundle install command. After that everything worked as expected.

Answer (score -3):

silly of me, you can access the file by browsing it thru terminal

$ open .rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values

and made changes on that file as shown on the link about.
Sorry new with ruby.

Comment: Modifying gems like this is incredibly dangerous and it will cause problems for you down the line.  I'd recommend restoring the gem to its original state "gem pristine activesupport" and updating rails in your Gemfile to obtain this fix.